# How to parse/Get the Node data from a XML response?

Tags: xml

How to parse/get the Location node value that is : New Delhi,India using looping and similarly how to get the multiple education node values like SVM,HHHHH etc from this xml file.
The XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facebookfriends>
<data>
<id>
[Removed]
    </id>
    <location>
        <id>
            [Removed]
        </id>
        <name>
            New Delhi, India
        </name>
    </location>
    <name>
        XYZZZZZZZZZZ
    </name>
    <education>
        <school>
            <id>
                [Removed]
            </id>
            <name>
                SVM
            </name>
        </school>
        <year>
            <id>
                [Removed]
            </id>
            <name>
                2001
            </name>
        </year>
        <type>
            High School
        </type>
    </education>
    <education>
        <concentration>
            <id>
                [Removed]
            </id>
            <name>
                Computer Science
            </name>
        </concentration>
        <school>
            <id>
                [Removed]
            </id>
            <name>
                HHHHHHHHHHHHH
            </name>
        </school>
        <type>
            Graduate School
        </type>
</education>
</data>

</facebookfriends>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jDom for this.. simple and easy-to-use...

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-jdom-example/

see the above link for examples...

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you to get the location/name node value from xml by parsing it. Similarly, you can get other node value by just changing the xpath.

```
        File xmlFile = new File("C:/face.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try{
            builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(xmlFile);
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String exp = "/facebookfriends/data/location/name";
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(exp).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); 
            }
        }catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```